# regex pattern between brackets

Tags: regex

Trying to find a pattern that matches

> (see ...)

Where the ellipses may be anything.

As far as I can see the regular expression should be

```
\(see*\)
```

Although

```
\(see
```

Will match the beginning of the pattern, the rest does not work. Is this to do with the space between "see" and the other characters?

Comment: It should be: `\(see.*?\)`

Comment: The asterisk `*` (also called kleene star) matches zero or more of the previous character. You are searching for zero or more `e` characters. You should use `.*` instead to match zero or more non-line-break characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, generally in regexes, `*` means 0 or more of the preceding character, so `see*` matches "see" and "seee" and "seeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee".  `.` matches any character, so `.*` is the usual way to match a bunch of unknown characters, such as:

```
\(see.*\)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a dot from your regular expression:

```
\(see.*\)
```